# Whats wrong with my palindrome? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I have written this js code for palindrome, I know there are better and more efficient palindrome methods online but I want to know why I am unable to get my palindrome function to work properly?

CODE:

```js
var pal = function(str) {

  var len = str.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var comp1 = str.substring(i, i + 1);

    for (var j = len; j > 0; j--) {
      var comp2 = str.substring(j - 1, j);
    }

    if (comp1 != comp2) {
      console.log("not palindrome")
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('palindrome')
    }
  }
}

pal('maddog');
```

OUTPUT :

```
palindrome
not palindrome
```

Comment: What do you think the inner loop does? It always sets `comp2` to the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of better algorithms to check Palindrome. Let use the similar algorithm that you are using.

We basically use two pointers - left and right, and move to middle at the same time. In the original question, left pointer and right pointer doesn't move at the same time.

Pointers should move like this -

```
a b c b a
^       ^

a b c b a
  ^   ^

a b c b a
    ^
```

```js
var isPalindrome = function (str) {
    for (var i = 0, j = str.length-1; i < j; i++ , j--) {
        if (str[i] != str[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log('maddog : ' + isPalindrome('maddog'));
console.log('abcba : ' + isPalindrome('abcba'));
console.log('deed : ' + isPalindrome('deed'));
console.log('a : ' + isPalindrome('a'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It works by dividing the string length by 2, and then iterating up, checking mirroring characters against each other:

```js
var pal = function(str){
    var len = str.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++){
        if(str[i] != str[(len-1)-i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(pal("bunny"));
console.log(pal("amoreroma"));
```

Comment: If you're gonna change the approach, you may as well go all out and `return str === str.split("").reverse().join("");`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the nested loops, you can just loop backwards through the string to invert the string and then compare it to the original string. I updated the Snippet to work.

Before, your code was not inverting the string but rather just iterating through the characters and assigning them to the `comp1` and `comp1` variables. You need to concatenate the strings in order to build the new string backwards `comp = comp + str.substring(j-1, j);`

```js
var pal = function(str) {

  var len = str.length;
  var comp = '';

  for (var j = len; j > 0; j--) {
    comp = comp + str.substring(j - 1, j);
  }

  if (str !== comp) {
    console.log("not palindrome")
    return;
  }
  
  console.log('palindrome')
}

pal('arepera');
```

Comment: try with a palindrome one

Comment: Both the "errors" you highlighted are not errors in general, and then they are not the reason why the code posted by the OP is not working

Comment: Re "*you must declare the comp2 variable outside the scope of the for loop*". Variables declared with *var* have function scope so that isn't an issue. Your changes don't affect the code in any meaningful way.

Comment: "You must declare the `comp2` variable outside the scope of the for loop". Wrong. JavaScript is function scoped, not block scoped when using the `var` keyword. JS will hoist the `var comp1;` to the top of the function for you. Also, triple equals compares value with no implicit type coercion.

Comment: @quirimmo the errors pointed out are causing the code to behave that way, I've updated the code to work for the intended purpose.

Comment: @mhodges You are right, I got confused there for a minute with the use of `foreach()` which would scope the variable declaration inside the block. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is totally unnecessary. It does the same thing every time -- it loops through the whole string, starting from the end, repeatedly setting `comp2` to the character; when it's done, `comp2` always contains the first character. So your function just tests whether every character in the string is the same as the first character.

To test if something is a palindrome, you need to compare each character with the corresponding character from the other end of the string. You don't need two loops for this. You also only need to loop through the first half of the string, not the whole string.

Finally, you should only echo `Palindrome` at the end of the loop. Inside the loop you only know that one character matches, not all of them.

```js
var pal = function(str) {

  var len = str.length;
  var half = Math.floor(len / 2);
  var isPal = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    var comp1 = str[i];
    var comp2 = str[len - i - 1];

    if (comp1 != comp2) {
      console.log("not palindrome")
      isPal = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isPal) {
    console.log('palindrome')
  }
}

pal('maddog');
pal('maddam');
```